# hl-line-mode interferes with custom syntax highlighting

Tags: font-lock, syntax-highlighting, hl-line-mode

Recently, using `fic-mode` as reference, I implemented a way for words like `TODO`, etc. to be highlighted. Here is the code:

```lisp
(defun todo/pos-in-doc-or-comment-region-p (pos)
  (memq (get-char-property pos 'face)
        '(font-lock-doc-face font-lock-comment-face)))

(defun todo/search-for-keyword (limit)
  (let ((original-match-data nil))
    (save-match-data
      (while (and (null original-match-data)
                  (re-search-forward "\\<\\(\\(\\(TODO(\\)\\([^)]+?\\)\\():\\)\\)\\|\\(\\(NOTE(\\)\\([^)]+?\\)\\():\\)\\)\\|\\(\\(FIXME(\\)\\([^)]+?\\)\\():\\)\\)\\|\\(\\(IMPORTANT(\\)\\([^)]+?\\)\\():\\)\\)\\)" limit t))
        (if (and (todo/pos-in-doc-or-comment-region-p (match-beginning 0))
                 (todo/pos-in-doc-or-comment-region-p (match-end 0)))
            (setq original-match-data (match-data)))))
    (when original-match-data
      (set-match-data original-match-data)
      (goto-char (match-end 0))
      t)))

(defvar todo/keywords
  '((todo/search-for-keyword  (3 font-lock-warning-face t t)
                              (4 font-lock-constant-face t t)
                              (5 font-lock-warning-face t t)
                              (7 font-lock-string-face t t)
                              (8 font-lock-constant-face t t)
                              (9 font-lock-string-face t t)
                              (11 font-lock-warning-face t t)
                              (12 font-lock-constant-face t t)
                              (13 font-lock-warning-face t t)
                              (15 font-lock-variable-name-face t t)
                              (16 font-lock-constant-face t t)
                              (17 font-lock-variable-name-face t t)
                              )))

(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook
          (lambda () (font-lock-add-keywords nil todo/keywords 'append)))
```

This was supposed to enable me to write things like `TODO(name): something` and have it properly highlighted like this:

[image: What I wanted].

However, if I enable `hl-line-mode` using `(global-hl-line-mode 1)`, the highlighting only happens if the point (cursor) is on a line different from the one on which the `TODO...` was typed. If I am on the same line, even doing `font-lock-fontify-buffer` does not refreshes syntax highlighting.

Also, once the highlighting has been "activated" (by pressing Enter, for example), if I come back to that line and edit something, the highlighting goes away once again.

[image: Clash of the Highlitan]

Can someone help as to how can I stop this clashing with `hl-line-mode`?

---

PS. I have set the line highlighting color using

```lisp
(set-face-background hl-line-face theme/color/woodsmoke) ; hl-line
```

### ------------------------------------------------------------

### Solution

Using the selected answer, putting

```lisp
(set-face-attribute 'hl-line nil :inherit nil :background theme/color/woodsmoke)
```

*before*

```lisp
(global-hl-line-mode 1)
```

fixes it.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate question, but I don't have time now to search for it. Maybe someone else can.

Comment: And this is not the first such duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you need to do is check the inheritance of the various faces.  This can be done with `describe-face`.  The available options are given in the manual under [Face Attributes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Attributes.html), but I believe the one you want is `unspecified`.

Here is what I use in my `init.el` for highlighting and how I solved the problem of the highlight clobbering other faces:

```
(load-theme 'tango-dark)
(global-hl-line-mode 1)
(set-face-attribute 'highlight nil :background "#3e4446" :foreground 'unspecified)
```

The first line changes the theme.  The theme has a highlight color of bright yellow which will become apparent when we enable highlighting.

[image]

When highlighting is enabled, the highlight is glorious yellow,

[image]

This yellow overrides other faces,

[image]

However, using `set-face-attribute`, I can define what the `:background` is and leave the `:foreground` unspecified, leaving space for other faces,

[image]

Comment: I replaced `(set-face-background hl-line-face theme/color/woodsmoke)` by `(set-face-attribute 'highlight nil :background theme/color/woodsmoke :foreground 'unspecified)` but it didn't work. 

Thanks for pointing out the inheritance though, I'll try to hack something later.

Comment: Also, hl-line doesn't really override any other syntax highlighting that comes bundled with Emacs, just this one that I've defined myself.

Comment: EUREKA!!! Putting `(set-face-attribute 'hl-line nil :inherit nil :background theme/color/woodsmoke)` **BEFORE** `(global-hl-line-mode 1)` fixes it. I really need a better text editor!

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why your solution works: AFAICT the problem is unrelated to what your faces are defined to look like.  Instead it's your `todo/pos-in-doc-or-comment-region-p` which will get confused because when `(get-char-property pos 'face)` is called it will be "blinded" by the `hl-line` face and won't see the underlying faces applied by `font-lock`.

A quick hack is to use `get-text-property` instead of `get-char-property` (since `hl-line-mode` uses an overlay rather than text-properties).  Personally I'd probably go for

```
(defun todo/pos-in-doc-or-comment-region-p (pos)
  (save-excursion (nth 8 (syntax-ppss pos)))
```

instead, tho.  Also, I hate `save-match-data` so I'd rewrite your loop as follows:

```
(defun todo/search-for-keyword (limit)
  (let (ret)
    (while
      (and (setq ret (re-search-forward "\\<\\(\\(\\(TODO(\\)\\([^)]+?\\)\\():\\)\\)\\|\\(\\(NOTE(\\)\\([^)]+?\\)\\():\\)\\)\\|\\(\\(FIXME(\\)\\([^)]+?\\)\\():\\)\\)\\|\\(\\(IMPORTANT(\\)\\([^)]+?\\)\\():\\)\\)\\)" limit t))
           (not (and (todo/pos-in-doc-or-comment-region-p (match-beginning 0))
                     (todo/pos-in-doc-or-comment-region-p (match-end 0))))))
    ret))
```